# how to migrate the .bot file based to new Sdk based bot?

Tags: botframework

I have followed all the steps mentioned [BOT DEPLOYMENT STEPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=newrg)!

However, since I have a  big code and I didn't want to change it so I didn't migrate the `.bot` file to `appsettings.json`.

Ignoring that step, I followed all other steps in the given page. but at the last steps when deploying the web BOT app, I am getting a JSON output:

```
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
  "end_time": "2019-06-13T13:14:49.6491874Z",
  "id": "61e25de338b94fce84f8cbe678bc8227",
  "is_readonly": true,
  "is_temp": false,
  "last_success_end_time": "2019-06-13T13:14:49.6491874Z",
  "log_url": "https://edmspeechtotranslatebot.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest/log",
  "message": "Created via a push deployment",
  "progress": "",
  "provisioningState": null,
  "received_time": "2019-06-13T13:14:04.3311237Z",
  "site_name": "edmspeechtotranslatebot",
  "start_time": "2019-06-13T13:14:04.6577488Z",
  "status": 4,
  "status_text": "",
  "url": "https://edmspeechtotranslatebot.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/deployments/latest"
}
```

I tried to check the logs. but it not very useful log:

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage":"No log found for 'latest'.",
"ExceptionType":"System.IO.FileNotFoundException",
"StackTrace":"
    at Kudu.Core.Deployment.DeploymentManager.GetLogEntries(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Core\\Deployment\\DeploymentManager.cs:line 95\r\n
   at Kudu.Services.Deployment.DeploymentController.GetLogEntry(String id) in C:\\Kudu Files\\Private\\src\\master\\Kudu.Services\\Deployment\\DeploymentController.cs:line 375"
}
```

I am seriously not sure how to deploy this bot to the portal now. but it other blogs post says that it will not be any problem to get it deploy. but I dont see any web app created on the portal. so please guide me if any expert out there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday. What happens when you run the bot locally?

Comment: Bot runs locally and is testable on emulator. But I still use the .bot file. do you use the same @JJ_Wailes?

Comment: I do. My issue was that my bot file wasn't included when I published, so I needed to redo the last few steps.

Comment: My other idea might be the level at which you're zipping the files. I've simplified some of the deployment steps from the doc into another deployment issue I'm working on [here](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1156). Look at my final comment (JWiley84, starts with 'Of course!'). It says 'Enterprise Bot' but it should work for any bot with a template.json file.